# Improving Java Graphics2D Quality

Tags: java, awt, java-2d, graphics2d

So, I'm drawing 100 concentric circles. However, when I try and render such a large amount of concentric circles with Graphics2D it starts to look a bit blurry and just generally unattractive (see pic).

```
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_DITHERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_DITHER_ENABLE);
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
```

I've done all this stuff, but this seems to be as good as it gets. Is there anything else I can do or is there another library that could get me a better result?

[image: Example of poor rendering.]

EDIT: This is all done by the fillOval method. Something like:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  x = getX(i);
  y = getY(i);
  length = getLength(i);
  g2.fillOval(x,y,length,length);
 }
```

Comment: That image burns my eyes :O Out of curiosity, why are you doing this?

Comment: It's just an...experiment...

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Depends on how you render it as well, as @AndrewThompson said, please post some code.

Comment: Another thing you can try is setting RenderingHints.KEY_STROKE_CONTROL to RenderingHints.VALUE_STROKE_NORMALIZE which will make strokes a little sharper or VALUE_STROKE_PURE which will make them more blended.

Comment: That may have helped a little, but still looks pretty poor unfortunately. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: I notice that since my first comment - you've posted an uncompilable code snippet.  Again, I recommend posting an SSCCE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The speckles you're seeing are artifacts of antialiased drawing of multiple objects with close-together edges. Since you don't show what `getLength(i)` is doing, I'm not sure, but it looks like you have multiple circles with very close or identical radii but different colors.

Try processing your data set (`getLength(i)`) so that you never draw a circle which is within some small threshold (say, 0.5 pixel) of being the same radius as the previous/next one. This will prevent the speckles from forming.

If you absolutely need to include all the detail, then I suggest you switch to a “procedural graphics” approach. This means that you generate the image using your own code:

```
For each (x, y) in the image bounds:
    Compute distance from center
    Find which circles the distance ± 1 pixel is touching
    Set pixel (x, y) to the weighted average of the colors of those circles based on how much of each circle fills the pixel
```

This will produce a “perfect” image without over-draw artifacts. This is effectively reimplementing antialiased circle drawing, but taking into account all the circles simultaneously rather than one at a time.

(Note that you can make this more efficient by computing the pixels for only 1/8 of the circle and mirroring/rotating it to cover the whole image.)

Comment: Sounds interesting. I'll take a look at both approaches, but,  switching to procedural graphics sounds like it could be good.

Comment: So I used a combination of the procedural graphics and removed any lengths from the image that were of equal length and it now looks pretty perfect. Thanks for the help.